# Identify a fixed phrase in an mp3 or wav file

Tags: mp3, wav

I would like to scan a mp3/wav for the phrase "Congratulations, you have successfully completed...".  This is from an IVR recording in which the phrase is pre-recorded and recited back to the customer as they complete an action.

What I am not sure about is: 
1) How to get a digital representation of the phrase I am seeking?
2) How to compare that digital representation to several thousand wav/mp3 files to see if it exists within the file.